# Close a different browser tab with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to close a *different* browser tab than the active one from another HTML page with Javascript?

I ask because I am building a virtual assistant in the browser. This assistant will open new tabs, at which point the current tab would be something like a Google search. If I could ask the virtual assistant to close this current tab, I would be returned to the virtual assistant browser window.

Comment: It should be possible, but javascript can only close windows it has opened, not random windows the user has opened.

Comment: Not sure why the thumb down. I searched as far and wide as I could for the answer, asking it on S.O. was not my first choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you opened the browser tab using `window.open` and if you have the reference to it, and it is from the same domain, yes, you can close it.

```
var myWin = null;

function openWin () {
  myWin = window.open("/hello.htm", "_blank");
}

function closeWin () {
  myWin.close();
}
```

Comment: Please close the dupes like this, if you cannot add to existing answers, don't answer such questions.